# simple defining function Python 27

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I'm writing a function that squares each element in the list.

```
def square(num):
    for i in range(len(num)):
        square[i] = square[i] ** 2

def action():
    nums = [2, 3, 4]
    print square(nums)


action()
```

It returns an error:

```
    square[i] = square[i] ** 2
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute `__getitem__`.
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `square` function you are referring to the function as if it's a list:

```
def square(num):
    for i in range(len(num)):
        square[i] = square[i] ** 2
```

Because `square` is not a list, Python tries to ask it for item `i` with the `__getitem__` method, but that doesn't exist either.

Perhaps you meant to use `num` instead?

```
def square(num):
    for i in range(len(num)):
        num[i] = num[i] ** 2
```

Comment: you're the man Martijn! and also if you don't mind, the last statement in the program `print square(nums)` returns the value of  `None` . I had to change it to `square(nums)` and `print nums`. I don't really get the subtle difference hmm..

Comment: @nutship: The default return value of a function is `None`; `square()` doesn't return anything, it cahnges `num` in-place. So `print square(nums)` prints the return value of `square()`, which is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

To build upon Martijn's answer:

```
def square(seq):
    for index in range(len(seq)):
        seq[index] = seq[index] ** 2
    return seq # this gives the output of the function
```

See: ['Return' in Python](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement).

Another way to do it (using a one-liner list comprehension):

```
def square(seq): return [x**2 for x in seq]
```

For list comprehensions, see: [Python List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

you cant use [] for functions, its for list or dict.

```
def square(num):
    l= [None] * len(num)
    for i in range(len(num)):
        l[i] = num[i] ** 2
    return l
```

Comment: Explain your answer more.